Необходима помощь с классом Directory
Короче, по заданию мне необходимо продемонстрировать работу классов Directory и DirectoryInfo. Когда я вбил тестовый образец одного метода, мне высветило ошибку, что имена методов не существуют в текущем контексте. Как мне это по итогу исправить? Ниже прилагаю код.
internal class Directory
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dirName = "E:\\";
        if (Directory.Exists(dirName)) //<-вот здесь на Exists
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Подкаталоги:");
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dirName); //<-и здесь на GetDirectories
            foreach (string s in dirs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Файлы:");
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dirName); //<-и тут на GetFiles
            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }

    }
}


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример. и дайте вопросу более осмысленный заголовок, кратко отражающий суть вопроса.

Имя вашего класса Directory совпадает с классом из System.IO, с которым вы хотите работать. Измените имя класса или обращайтесь к System.IO.Directory по полному имени: if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(dirName))

@AlexF дополнительно: Вылезла ошибка, что для программы определено несколько точек входа. Компиляция с /main позволит указать тип, содержащий точку входа.

@Студент221, так у вас по факту получилось 2 метода main() - 2 точки входа: одна неявная в  Program.cs, если приложение консольное, и вторая - в вашем классе.

И что мне в таком случае надо сделать?

Вам выше все довольно доходчиво объяснили ведь. Вы не можете в класса Dictionary использовать другой класс с аналогичным названием (Dictionary) без указания явного namespace. Получается длинно и не хотите переименовывать класс? Используйте Alias, пишите в самом верху что-то по типу using SomeName = System.IO.Directory;, где SomeName - любое название, а затем в коде используйте не Directory.GetFiles(), а SomeName.GetFiles(). Что касается 2-й ошибки, то также, скази уже все. У вас не может быть в одном проекте два метода Main, ибо это стартовая точка проекта. Переименуйте метод.

Про класс я уже понял. Вторую проблему решил переписыванием проги.

@Студент221 А вы не ищите легких путей :) Надо было метод main класса Directory переименовать в какой-нибудь DoWork например, а в Program.cs создать экземпляр класса Directory dir = new(); и вызвать у него метод dir.DoWork(), ну или сразу Directory.DoWork()- если метод статическим оставите, ну и с namespace-ами порядок навести

Как подсказали в комментариях, у меня совпадало название класса с системным классом.
Вторую возникшую ошибку я не понимаю как исправил, понял только то, что у меня откуда-то вторая функция main() появилась.
Исправленный код:
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dirName = "C:\\";
        if (Directory.Exists(dirName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Подкаталоги:");
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dirName);
            foreach (string s in dirs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Файлы:");
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dirName);
            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}

